# Select first input, but don't select type=hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, hidden

I want to focus the first input element that is not `type=hidden`. I've got this far but it will still attempt to focus hidden elements.

```
$('#content input:first').focus();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `:visible` selector:

```
$('#content input:visible:first').focus();
```

`:visible` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

> Description: Selects all elements that are visible. Elements can be
>   considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> - They have a CSS display value of none.
> - They are form elements with  type="hidden".
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> - An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

If it's too much for you, use `Attribute Not Equal Selector`:

```
$('#content input[type!="hidden"]:first').focus();
```

`Attribute Not Equal Selector` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/):

> Description: Select elements that either don't have the specified attribute, or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value.

Comment: Nice, didn't even know there was a :visible. Thanks, works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#content input:first').not(":hidden").focus();
```

Comment: I find this better: `$('#content input[type!="hidden"]:first').focus();`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to select the element filtering with its attribute and appearing first.

```
$("#content input[type!='hidden']:first").focus();
```